# Can Zxing support these barcode formats

Tags: android, zxing, ean-13, gs1-databar, gs1-qr-code

I am new to the ZXing environment and I have previously used it only once for QR codes for android...
My question is:

Can ZXing decode the following barcode variants:

(1) **UPC GS1-12**
  (2) **EAN GS1-13**
(3) **RSS GS1 Databar**
(4)**QR-GS1 Codes**

Can anyone direct me proper resources or can throw their opinions on this? THnks in advance :))

Comment: You will be better served reading [the project documentation](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) and asking follow-up questions on [the ZXing Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/zxing).

Comment: yes I went through the documentation, it mentions the support for UPC, EAN, RSS and QR but I am specifically looking for feedback based on these formats ....

Comment: And when you asked your questions on the ZXing Google Group, what did they tell you?

Comment: Its still awaiting an approval to get posted there....

Comment: Ah, OK. You might be able to get help here, but on deep-in-the-weeds questions like this, it's usually better to go to the project itself where possible.

Comment: thnks :)), just trying my luck here :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copied from the discussion group -- follow up there, or here)

These are not new formats. These are just UPC, EAN, QR code and RSS (-14 probably). GS1 is a standards group that is trying to define something new about what is encoded in the barcodes. In the case of UPC/EAN I don't even think that's new. There is no special handling of GS1 contents, but the contents are decoded just fine.

Comment: Got ur answer at the Zxing group ! Great thanks ! :))